# Returning a string that incorporates what the method calculates

Tags: ruby

I have:

```
tv_sales = 601.5
```

Using this value, I want to return the following string:

```
"The total dollar amount of TVs sold today was 601.50."
```

Here's my code:

```
def two_decimals(number) 
  puts sprintf('%0.2f', number)
end

puts "The total dollar amount of TVs sold today was #{two_decimals(tv_sales).to_s}."
#=> 601.50
#=> The total dollar amount of TVs sold today was
```

How can I get the return to be on one line, and in the proper order?

Comment: Do you want to return or print? They are completely different things.

Comment: Cannot be reproduced.

Comment: Take out the first `puts`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what your code is doing:

```
def two_decimals(number) 
  puts sprintf('%0.2f', number)  # => nil
end

tv_sales = 601.5                                                                          
puts "The total dollar amount of TVs sold today was #{two_decimals(tv_sales).to_s}."  # => nil

# >> 601.50
# >> The total dollar amount of TVs sold today was .
```

- The first `puts` outputs the result of `sprintf('%0.2f', number)`, which is `601.50`, displayed first in the output.
- Then Ruby returns the result of `puts` when it exits `two_decimals`, resulting in `nil`.
- That value is being interpolated into the string containing the call to `two_decimals`, resulting in `The total dollar amount of TVs sold today was .`.

Fix it by removing the first `puts`:

```
def two_decimals(number) 
  sprintf('%0.2f', number)  # => "601.50"
end

tv_sales = 601.5
puts "The total dollar amount of TVs sold today was #{two_decimals(tv_sales).to_s}."  # => nil

# >> The total dollar amount of TVs sold today was 601.50.
```

Ruby will see `601.50` as the return value of `sprintf` and return it, which will be interpolated into the string as you want.

It's not necessary to use `to_s` in the string, it's automatically supplied by Ruby when you interpolate into a string:

```
"#{two_decimals(tv_sales).to_s}"  # => "601.50"
"#{two_decimals(tv_sales)}"       # => "601.50"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your method should return value (implicitly – as last evaluated expression, or explicitly – with `return`), not output it, so it can be interpolated in your string afterwards:

```
def two_decimals number
  sprintf '%0.2f', number
end
```

[**Demo**](https://repl.it/BinS)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following code:

```
def two_decimals(number)
  number.round(2)
end

puts "The total dollar amount of TVs sold today was #{two_decimals(tv_sales)}."
```

You need to return a number, not an output method, so that it can be translated into a string.